# Sitecore Page Editor not working after Update to 6.6

Tags: editor, sitecore, sitecore6

After updating our Sitecore 6.3 to 6.6, the Page Editor doesn't work. Instead there's this error message where the Page Editor should be at the top of the page:

```
Server Error in Application ./

    [ArgumentException: Empty strings are not allowed.

Parametername: name]

   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(String argument, String argumentName) +241

   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager.GetCommand(String name) +29

   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbon.RenderButtons(HtmlTextWriter output, Item item, Boolean hasRibbon) +434

   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbon.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +471

   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108

   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394
```

We installed made the necessary config files changes. Backend and the Website are working fine.

Anyone knows how to fix the Page Editor?

EDIT:
Thanks to Martin I found the items with the missing fields in the Core Database. Now I have the problem that when I want to save those items after filling the necessary fields, I get this error message:

```
[NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.]


Sitecore.Intranet.FrontendEditing.FrontendEditor.IsAutoVersioningEnabledForItem(Item item) +69
   Sitecore.Intranet.Pipelines.SaveUI.AddNewVersion.Process(SaveArgs args) +515

[TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct&amp; sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +1255
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +38
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args) +318
   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline) +330
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.DoStart(PipelineArgs args) +208
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic) +182
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RunPipelines() +280
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +530
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394



[NullReferenceException]: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei Sitecore.Intranet.FrontendEditing.FrontendEditor.IsAutoVersioningEnabledForItem(Item item)
   bei Sitecore.Intranet.Pipelines.SaveUI.AddNewVersion.Process(SaveArgs args)
[TargetInvocationException]: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args)
   bei Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline)
   bei Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.DoStart(PipelineArgs args)
   bei Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
   bei Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RunPipelines()
   bei Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   bei Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
[HttpUnhandledException]: Eine Ausnahme vom Typ &quot;System.Web.HttpUnhandledException&quot; wurde ausgel&#246;st.
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   bei ASP.sitecore_shell_applications_content_manager_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a348ed6\6269aa05\App_Web_x1rqdwhm.1.cs:Zeile 0.
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Have you made any changes to the core database? If not, just attach a clean Sitecore 6.6 core database. Remember to copy across users from the AspNet Membership tables.

Comment: We have lots of custom stuff in the Core DB, so unfortunaletly that wouldn't work for us.

Comment: You should mark Martin's answer as correct answer and ask your new question as a separate question. It doesn't have much in common with the title of the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the exception it looks like one or more of the buttons defined for the page editor in the core database have an empty `Click` field.

Go in to the core database and check the buttons items which I think are at `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/Standalone Buttons`.

I would recommend comparing what you see with the same location in a basic install of 6.6.

Comment: Thanks Martin, those itms indeed have empty Click fields. But when I want to save them, I get an error message (I edited the first post with that error message).